# Http GET call failure in practice (checked with web HTTP test and was successful)

Tags: java, android

Trying to get a response from server failed constantly.
the JSON I'm trying to GET is this :

http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=d4fa53a5bb8f9eccdedcd42d647de093&symbols=ILS,EUR,USD,AUD,CAD,GBP,JPY,RUB

and I'm reading it right into "response" object and "rates" object inside it. (code attached below)

The response object:

```java
public class Response {
    public boolean success; // changed to boolean, was string before
    public int timestamp;
    public String base;
    public String dateString;
    public Rate rates;
}
```

The rate object:

```java
public class Rate {
    public static float ILS;
    public static float EUR;
    public static float USD;
    public static float AUD;
    public static float CAD;
    public static float GBP;
    public static float JPY;
    public static float RUB;

    public static float getConversionRate(String baseRateName, String targetRateName) {
        Map<String,Float> rates = new HashMap<String,Float>();
        rates.put("ILS",ILS);
        rates.put("€",EUR);
        rates.put("$",USD);
        rates.put("AUD",AUD); // sign same as dollar, we wont use it
        rates.put("CAD",CAD); // sign same as dollar, we wont use it
        rates.put("£",GBP);
        rates.put("¥",JPY); // yen, japan
        rates.put("RUB",RUB); // rubel, russia

        Float baseRate = rates.get(baseRateName);
        Float targetRate = rates.get(targetRateName);

        if (baseRate == null) {
            baseRate = 1.0f;
        }
        if (targetRate == null) {
            targetRate = 1.0f;
        }

        // return the conversion rate
        return targetRate / baseRate;
    }
}
```

The actuall call in main activity:

```java
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://data.fixer.io/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        FixerApi fixerApi = retrofit.create(FixerApi.class);
        Call<Response> call = fixerApi.getResponse();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    fixerRate.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                    return;
                }
                // if successful!
                fixerResponse = response.body();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Failed to get response from server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: print onFailure Throwable t and share

use this log (t.printStackTrace();)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see one thing, which isn't right. Since you don't use `@SerializedName` annotations, you should change `dateString` to `date` so it match with API (look as JSON, name of the field is "date", not "dateString").

Second thing is check please, if you need front slash after your URL inside `BASE_URL`. I used to call methods without it, and I didn't have front slashes before certain methods either.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for both of you. still a problem while reading rates:

First, I fixed the field mentioned by SkypeDogg. Secondly, I didn't know how to see the -  t.printStackTrace(); logfile so I came across using this:

```
Log.e(TAG, "Exception: "+Log.getStackTraceString(t));
```

then it showed me that I need to enable ClearTextTraffic (which is disabled by default from android 9.)

by adding - android:usesCleartextTraffic="true", while I am not getting to failure but it seems that the response failed to initialize the fetched values from rest specifically the rates object.

[image: here I get the response into response object]
and here is the response:

[image: "shadows klass" which is not clear to me]